# Replacing specifing character in arguments of request via NGINX

Tags: nginx, args

I am trying to replace specific character (+ plus sign) in arguments part to space character (%20).
I made rewrite for path part but while testing I learned that NGINX doesn't change arguments after ? sign (I am new to NGINX).

I tried to do it for args part of configuration but it doesn't work as it should, it adds $20 until I get error that page isn't redirecting correctly.

The request URL ) I receive is always the same.

```
func=autocomplete&q=<(unlimited number of letters and plus signs (mostly 4-5 plus signs)>&key_lic=xxxxx
```

The code in NGINX configurations is following.

```
location /autocomplete/luka/ {
        if ($args ~* "^([^+]*)(\+?)([^+]*)(\+?)([^+]*)(\+?)(.*)$"){
                set $args $1%20$3%20$5%20$7;
                rewrite  (.*)$ $1 redirect;
         }
        proxy_pass http://link.where.to.finish/wm2/;
 }
```

Thank you for any help I could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing scheme fails because all of the `+` signs are optional.

If you want to redirect your URI to one where all of the `+` signs are replaced by `%20`, you can just use a space and let Nginx and/or the browser handle the encoding.

For example:

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)\+(.*)$) { return 302 "$uri?$1 $2"; }
```

The redirect is recursive until all `+` signs are replaced.

---

If you intention is to correct the URI without redirection, so that only the upstream server sees the `+` signs replaced by `%20`, use `rewrite...last` instead.

For example:

```
if ($args ~ ^(?<first>.*)\+(?<second>.*)$) { 
    rewrite ^(.*)$ "$1?$first%20$second?" last; 
}
```

In this case it is necessary to use named captures in the first regular expression so that they can be used in the second. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification of my mistake and answering my question. Your solution solved my issue.

Comment: How does this work? $1 contains the entire URI I presume but $first and $second contain everything before the first + and after respectively?

Comment: @user2399453 `$1` contains the URL *without* the arguments. `$first` and `$second` contain the arguments either side of the first `+` and the `rewrite` converts this into a space (or `%20` when it goes external). The `rewrite...last` is recursive because the `if` block is *inside* a `location` block - so eventually all `+`s will be converted (until Nginx declares a redirection loop after about 10 iterations).

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to handle the case where there are more than 10 occurences? I actually asked a separate question too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657783/nginx-rewrite-args/